# Present perfect or future perfect with "by then" in an imperative

Tags: grammar, tenses

The sentences:

- Make sure you've finished your assignments by then
- Make sure you'll have finished your assignments by then

I know that in normal sentences (not imperatives), you use future perfect with *by then*. For example: *I will have finished those assignments by then*. What about imperatives? They both sound odd. Should I have used this instead: *Make sure to finish your assignments by then*?

Comment: Both sentences sound fine—with the first one being a bit more natural than the second. But there's also nothing wrong with your third version. (My own preference is for the first version.)

Comment: @JasonBassford I see. For some reason, I find them rather strange... Thank you for the input, though.

Comment: I don't like the second bullet.  It sounds like the character in "Jane the Virgin" who thinks that proposing marriage to a woman can be done by getting down on one knee and saying, "Petra, my dear, you WILL MARRY ME!"